# Release and target name is 'null' in AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm using ItelliJ and trying to set up an Android development environment.

When I look a the AVD Manager some entries are `null`.

[image: AVD Manager with null entries]

- Why is this?
- Is this normal or is there something I should be fixing here?

I'm using:

- IntelliJ 2016.2.5
- Windows 10
- Android SDK Manager 23.2.3

Comment: I'm getting the same thing using Android Studio 3.1.3, Windows 10, SDK Tools 28.0.1.  Just started happening and now I cannot launch any emulators. Not sure if it's the same issue, but thought I'd mention here.

Comment: Upgraded to Android Studio 3.2 Beta and the null went away.  Also figured out that my emulator started having problems when I turned on Hyper-V b.c. HAXM and Hyper-V are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If the emulator will boot up, this is probably just a UI bug. You can check the emulator settings with the command `android list avd`. The `android` binary used to run this command is in your Android SDK directory, under `tools`. The full path for a typical setup is `~/Android/Sdk/tools/android`.